# Multibit HD only sees one peer

Tags: peers, multibit-hd

Multibit HD is only connecting with one peer.  This issue randomly started a few weeks ago.  Initially, I had to keep restoring my wallet to a previous date since my balance kept reverting to uncomfirmed. Annoying but it was a work around, until it only started connecting with one peer.  Restoring the wallet does not resolve this issue.

Bitcoin Core works just fine.  Ports 8330 and 8333 are open.  The issue happens both on, and off, a vpn.

Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot this issue, or at least get my coins out?

Thanks!

Comment: Restoring this wallet on a different PC worked.  I then moved my coins to a different wallet.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Multibit HD is long obsolete, no one should still be using it and this question has no upvoted or still useful answers

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I had Bitcoin Core running.  Shutting down Bitcoin Core and restarting Multibit fixed the issue.

I'm guessing the issue was that Bitcoin Core had exclusive access to port 8333.  If you are not running Bitcoin Core, check for other software that might use that port.